# Maya python incomplete autocompletion

Tags: python, maya, code-completion

I'm really new with python programming in Maya and I'm trying to find a confortable way to write code
I would like to have an IDE where if I write "cmds.ls" the autocompletion give me the list off all the arguments
What I have now is a completion with some pointers and a function with "pass" inside
I know that until some version ago it was possible to have the list of all the arguments.
Am I wrong?
If I open the file "maya.cmds.pypredef" I have a list of function just declared with "pass" in the scope

Comment: I must say I was never able to make it happen anywhere. I normally end up searching them on the script editor and using the script editor autocomplete. Then, I copy that into my IDE.

Answer (score 2):

I never used auto-completion but here is an easy way to get it in Sublime Text, I was not able to get the arguments though, only the function names. You should be able to do the same thing for any other IDE in a similar way.

- Go into your Maya install *folder/MayaXXXX/devkit/other/pymel/extras/completion/py*.
- If that hierarchy doesn't exists and stops at devkit, there is a README with a link to download the devkit file for your Maya version.
- Download the Maya Developer Kit and replace the folders (devkit, include, etc.) in your Maya installation.
- Install the Jedi Package in Sublime Text (or any other)
- Add that to the Jedi user settings file:

  ```
   {
       "python_package_paths": ["folder/MayaXXXX/devkit/other/pymel/extras/completion/py"]
   }
  ```

You are all set!

To use the auto completion, make sure it is activated in Sublime Text and that you work on a Python file, import the maya.cmds module and do a Ctrl + Space. The auto-completion window should appear with all the cmds commands.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.
```

The arguments do not seem to be implemented in the Maya devkit, they seem to be set as `*args, **keywords` for all functions. I don't remember seeing any auto-completion with arguments in Maya, and if it exists I am interested!

([Source](http://www.janpijpers.com/mel-autocompletion-for-sublime-and-mayasublime/))

---

After fiddling with the arguments of the functions in the file **MayaXXXX\devkit\other\pymel\extras\completion\py\maya\cmds\__init__.py**, I can say that it is not possible to have the auto-completion with the arguments unless Autodesk correctly build this file with them.

Maybe someone took the time to do it and shared the file, but I doubt it.

Comment: Exactly what I feared.
Thanks in any case.